# How to get rows when their first 8 digits matched which are compared

Tags: c#

I need to get values which are compared from 2 columns when their only first 8 digits matched

here is some code

```
string[] titles1 = a.Split(new[] { ';', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] titles2 = b.Split(new[] { ';', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var Result = titles1.Union(titles2).Except(titles2).ToArray();
```

```
For Example:

Column-1                 Column-2
'89118432 20190602'      '89115496 20190602'
'89114023 20180602'      '89114023 20180602'
'89110101 20190602'      '89118432 20170602'


 It's value i need 
'89118432 20190602'
```

Comment: Or also look at overloaded [Union](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) and [Excep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) methods with `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` parameter.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421170/c-sharp-distinct-liststring-by-substring

Comment: especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421740/6560478) answer. Using [`Compare(String strA, int indexA, String strB, int indexB, int length)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_Int32_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_). To compare 2 string based on

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
string[] column1 = new[]
{
    "89118432 20190602",
    "89114023 20180602",
    "89110101 20190602"
};
string[] column2 = new[]
{
    "89115496 20190602",
    "89114023 20180602",
    "89118432 20170602"
};

// first by using union, making them as a single array
List<IGrouping<string, string>> dataList = column1.Union(column2)
                     .GroupBy(x => string.Join("", x.Take(8))).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();
// then by using Take extension, we took first 8 character. By Where extension we searched over array that 8 characters if exists more then 1.
```

[image]

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
string[] column1Data = new[]
{
    "89118432 20190602",
    "89114023 20180602",
    "89110101 20190602"
};
string[] column2Data = new[]
{
    "89115496 20190602",
    "89114023 20180602",
    "89118432 20170602"
};

string[] filteredData =  column1Data.Where(str1 => 
   column2Data.Any(
       str2 => str2.Substring(0, 8).Equals(str1.Substring(0, 8))
       && !str2.Substring(8).Equals(str1.Substring(8))
       )
   ).ToArray();
```

Comment: there is condition of not equals on remaining data(data except first 8 digit) of column2Data. So Hashset will might not be useful. `!str2.Substring(8).Equals(str1.Substring(8))`

Comment: and how to get unmatched values ?