# How to iterate only distinct string values by custom substring equality

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25421170/6844481) question, I'm trying to iterate only distinct values of sub-string of given strings, for example:

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>()
{
    "foo_boo_1",
    "foo_boo_2,
    "foo_boo_3,
    "boo_boo_1"
}
```

The output for the selected distinct values **should be** (select arbitrary the first sub-string's distinct value):

> foo_boo_1 (the first one)
>   boo_boo_1

I've tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421215/6844481) solution using the `IEqualityComparer` with:

```
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {            
        int xIndex = x.LastIndexOf("_"); 
        int yIndex = y.LastIndexOf("_");
        if (xIndex > 0 && yIndex > 0)
            return x.Substring(0, xIndex) == y.Substring(0, yIndex);
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}

foreach (var key in myList.Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(key)    
}
```

But the resulted output is:

> foo_boo_1
>   foo_boo_2
>   foo_boo_3
>   boo_boo_1

**Using the `IEqualityComparer` How do I remove the sub-string distinct values (`foo_boo_2` and `foo_boo_3`)?**

*Please note that the "real" keys are a lot longer, something like "1_0_8-B153_GF_6_2", therefore I must use the LastIndexOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation has some *flaws*:

1. Both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` *must* never *throw exception* (you have to check for `null`)
2. If `Equals` returns `true` for `x` and `y` then `GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)`. *Counter example* is `"abc_1"` and `"abc_2"`.

The *2nd* error can well cause `Distinct` return *incorrect results* (`Distinct` first compute hash).

Correct code can be something like this

```
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> {
  public bool Equals(string x, string y) {            
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    else if ((null == x) || (null == y))
      return false;

    int xIndex = x.LastIndexOf('_'); 
    int yIndex = y.LastIndexOf('_');

    if (xIndex >= 0)         
      return (yIndex >= 0) 
        ? x.Substring(0, xIndex) == y.Substring(0, yIndex)
        : false;
    else if (yIndex >= 0)         
      return false;
    else
      return x == y; 
  }

  public int GetHashCode(string obj) {
    if (null == obj)  
      return 0;

    int index = obj.LastIndexOf('_');

    return index < 0 
      ? obj.GetHashCode() 
      : obj.Substring(0, index).GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Now you are ready to use it with `Distinct`:

```
   foreach (var key in myList.Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer())) {
     Console.WriteLine(key)    
   }
```

Comment: Hey @dmitry, great answer. can you please explain why the breakpoint does not break inside the `Equals(...)`?

Comment: @Shahar Shokrani: `Distinct` compares `x` and `y` in **2** stages: 1st it compares *hashes*; if hash codes are different there's not need to call `Equals` and only if hash codes are *equal* it runs `Equals`. Our hashes are good, and it can well appear we don't need `Equals` at all

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetHashCode` method in your equality comparer is returning the hash code for the entire string, just make it hash the substring, for example:

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
    var index = obj.LastIndexOf("_");
    return obj.Substring(0, index).GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Hey @DavidG, thanks, What about the `Equals(...)`? can I leave it as NotImplementedException?

Comment: The `Equals` method won't even be called because all your strings are different. Make this change and it will be.

Comment: When the Equals get called?

Comment: You know, you can debug this code and work that out for yourself right?

Comment: I've already tried to put a breakpoint inside the `Equals(...)` but it won't break. when I make it as `NotImplementedException` the program crash. It seem to work only when the `Equals(...)` refer the `GetHashCode(...)`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a more succinct solution that avoids using a custom `IEqualityComparer<>`, you could utilise `GroupBy`. For example:

```
var keys = new List<string>()
{
    "foo_boo_1",
    "foo_boo_2",
    "foo_boo_3",
    "boo_boo_1"
};

var distinct = keys
    .Select(k => new
    {
        original = k,
        truncated = k.Contains("_") ? k.Substring(0, k.LastIndexOf("_")) : k
    })
    .GroupBy(k => k.truncated)
    .Select(g => g.First().original);
```

This outputs:

> foo_boo_1
>
> boo_boo_1

Comment: Nice but what about index is -1